# Java commons-math Issue forming and extracting verices of ConvexHull2D

Tags: java, geometry, convex-hull, apache-commons-math

I am working on ConvexHull problem and I need to identify vertices of a convex hull. I am using Apache commons-math's - ConvexHull2D. Here is what I have so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vector2D v1 = new Vector2D(1, 3);
        Vector2D v2 = new Vector2D(-1, 3);
        Vector2D v3 = new Vector2D(0, -2);
        Vector2D v4 = new Vector2D(-1, -3);
        Vector2D v5 = new Vector2D(-12, -13);
        Vector2D v6 = new Vector2D(-10, -30);

        Vector2D[] vertices = {v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6};
        double tolerance = 1;

        ConvexHull2D ch = new ConvexHull2D(vertices, tolerance);
        vertices =ch.getVertices();

        System.out.println(vertices);

    }
```

But with this code I am seeing this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.math3.exception.MathIllegalArgumentException: vertices do not form a convex hull in CCW winding
    at org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.euclidean.twod.hull.ConvexHull2D.<init>(ConvexHull2D.java:69)
    at run_ootb_templates.LongitudeLatitudeTest.main(LongitudeLatitudeTest.java:22)
```

My understanding of the convex hull is any 3 points in space are capable of forming a convex hull and any additional point other than these 3 can be accommodated in this boundary of convex hull.

Any help towards resolution is appreciated, also if any sample datasets so that I can understand this

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for this area of Apache commons-math doesn't seem very good, but from
looking at the [source code](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.5/src-html/org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/euclidean/twod/hull/ConvexHull2D.html) it's clear that `ConvexHull2D` requires the vertices to already form a convex polygon. This is enforced by checking for a consistent turning direction as you move along the boundary. Your points don't form a convex polygon, hence the exception.

Instead what you want is to use an implementation of the [ConvexHullGenerator2D](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/euclidean/twod/hull/ConvexHullGenerator2D.html) interface, e.g. [MonotoneChain](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/euclidean/twod/hull/MonotoneChain.html), to build a `ConvexHull2D` via the `generate(Collection<Vector2D> points)` method.